# Flexbox layout on latest Safari - squished vs stretched out content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, cross-browser

In the example code below I have a complex structure of nested containers which represents blue boxes in flex containers. The whole thing is nested ina scroll container.

[image]

The issue is that the blue containers are squished on Safari:

[image]

There are lots of examples here on SO which concern such an issue. The accepted solution in most of them is to add `flex-shrink: 0`;

In my case, this would mean adding flex-shrink to the `.stackchild` and `#StackChild`. This is a styled react component but for the sake of the example, the random CSS classes are replaced with a class and id just to be distinguished.

When I add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `stackchild` I get another layout issue on all browsers:

[image]

Tbh I'm not quite sure what's going on here ...
Any idea why does the shrink prop break the layout in this way? And how to solve this so that all browsers are happy?

Code example here: https://codepen.io/pollx/pen/oNbmEoE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a min height alongside stack child appears to work.
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

```
.stackchild {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: calc(16px / 2);
  margin-bottom: calc(16px / 2);
  min-height: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jspenc/pen/rNxEOme